# How to get certain data in while loop not to repat

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have tried moving the data first name and last name out of the loop but I get nothing shown for the data. I was wondering if it is possible to only repeat the product, price, quantity and not the first and last name?

```
<?php
include ('dbconnect.php');
$sql='SELECT * FROM `user_info` ,`customer_order` WHERE user_info.user_id=customer_order.uid';

        $run_query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);


    if(! $run_query ) {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());
   }

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
      echo "name:{$row['first_name']}   ".
            "Last:{$row['last_name']}  <br> ".
            "Product:{$row['p_name']}  <br> ".
            "Price:{$row['p_price']}  <br> " .
            "Quanity:{$row['p_qty']}  <br> ";

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to simplify the code shown above, and because SQL statements are relatively quick to execute, I'd suggest to break your statement in two: First fetch first/last names, then run a loop that will get the list of cells you need.

```
<?php
include ('dbconnect.php');
// Fetch user info
$sql='SELECT * FROM `user_info` WHERE user_info.user_id=customer_order.uid';
$run_query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

if(! $run_query ) {
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());
}
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo "Customer: name:{$row['first_name']} ".
     "Last:{$row['last_name']} <br>" ;

// Fetch every orders needed
$sql='SELECT `p_name`, `p_price`, `p_qty` FROM `user_info`, `customer_order` WHERE `user_info.user_id=customer_order.uid';
$run_query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if(! $run_query ) {
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    echo "Product:{$row['p_name']} <br> ".
         "Price:{$row['p_price']}  <br> " .
         "Quantity:{$row['p_qty']}  <br> ";
}
```

Comment: **PS**: The [mysqli_fetch_all](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) should not be used in case the number of rows you're trying to fetch is too high. That would literraly eat your ram by storing a gigantic table.
**PS2**: Back when I used PHP, I used to use an utility function that does all the 
connection/execution/error handling on it's own, providing a oneline to execute any statement. Which can get quite ugly

Answer (score 0):

Try this with a if statement in the loop to check if you are displaying the same names or not :

```
<?php
include ('dbconnect.php');
$sql='SELECT * FROM `user_info` ,`customer_order` WHERE user_info.user_id=customer_order.uid';

        $run_query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);


    if(! $run_query ) {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());
   }

   $first_name_saved = "";
   $last_name_saved = "";
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
      if ($first_name_saved != row["first_name"] && $last_name_saved != row["first_name"]){
      echo "name:{$row['first_name']}   ".
            "Last:{$row['last_name']}  <br> ";
        }
        echo    "Product:{$row['p_name']}  <br> ".
            "Price:{$row['p_price']}  <br> " .
            "Quanity:{$row['p_qty']}  <br> ";

            $first_name_saved = $row['first_name'];
            $last_name_saved = $row['last_name'];


        }
```

Comment: actually it is still doing same thing. I needed to get the first name and last name not to repeat with the same products ordered from that user

Comment: Thanks Pierre for help but wonskcalb answer is what I was looking for.